# Putting JSON inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to ask because I doubt it. Can I put a JSON inside JSON? Like this.

```
var json = { 
 test = { "name":"test", "age":"99" };
};
```

So I can use it like this :

```
console.log(json.test.name);
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, use `:` and not `=` as your outer json has to be a valid `JSON` object and should contain `key:value` pair. Also remove the `;` from `test = { "name":"test", "age":"99" };`

Comment: That's not JSON. That's just JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your syntax is just wrong:

```
var json = { 
 test: { "name":"test", "age":"99" }
     ^^                            ^^ no semi-colon
};
```

And for clarification, what you have is a *Javascript Object Literal*, not JSON. JSON is a string representation of a Javascript Object**

** Simplified explanation. Full details http://json.org/

Comment: put `test` into double-quotes or it's not json

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich It's not JSON anyway.

Comment: well. question title suggests so.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich But it's not. By that logic, I should point out that `var json = {` is invalid JSON, but I didn't because it's not JSON at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your json :

```
var jsonVar = {test :{ "name":"test", "age":"99" }};
```

Also avoid creating a variable using reserved words like json. use jsonVar, jsonVal etc.

```
console.log(jsonVar);
console.log(jsonVar.test);
console.log(jsonVar.test.name);
console.log(jsonVar.test.age);
```

and their respective ans in firebug console.

```
Object { test={...}}
Object { name="test",  age="99"}
test
99
```